# How can I force a .com domain to redirect to .tld

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains, let's say `example.com` and `example.tld`. But I want that users always get to the `.tld` domain. I want to use `.htaccess` and have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.tld/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

When I open `example.com`, it redirects to `example.tld`. But when I open `example.tld` I get an error

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
```

How do I have to modify the redirection statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you will need a `RewriteCond` to ensure that the subsequent `RewriteRule` is only applied when the requested `HTTP_HOST` was `example.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Apply the rule if the host does not already match example.tld
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.tld$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.tld/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Note that when using `[R]`, the `[QSA]` is already implicit. You don't actually need to add it here but it doesn't hurt.

The above would redirect *any* domain other than `example.tld` into `example.tld`. If you added a third domain which you did not want to redirect (redirecting only `example.com`), instead of the negative match in `RewriteCond`, you could use a positive match for that domain only.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.tld/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, not only for the fix, but also for the hint at the end.